# How do I use a variable Char* with the function TEXT() in C

Tags: c, text, char, literals, string-literals

I have a problem of variable conversion.

I have a function in my program like this:

```
function(Char* request) {
    ret = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, request, SQL_NTS);
    // ...
}
```

However, this function doesn't work but, if I change the line like below, it works:

```
function(Char* request) {
    ret = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, TEXT("SELECT * FROM..."), SQL_NTS);
    // ...
}
```

So, since I can't do TEXT(request), how can I convert my SQL char* variable to a TEXT() version?

Comment: I assume this is the TEXT macro from the w indows headers. See what it does, when UNICODE is defined, it expands to a unicode string literal, otherwise to an ascii string literal. Therefore the "TEXT version" as you call it depends on how you compile.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `TEXT(xxx)` macro is either a *wide* character string literal (`const wchar_t*`) or a *plain* character literal (`const char*`), depending on whether or not the `UNICODE` macro is defined.

However, as you have noted, you can't use the macro on anything other than *literals*; so, it's of no use in converting a `char*` *variable*.

To achieve your result, in a way that works for both Unicode and non-Unicode builds, you can use a temporary buffer array of type `TCHAR[n]` (the `TCHAR` type changes in parallel with the `TEXT` macro), and write your (fixed) `char*` data to that, using the `_stprintf()` function.

Here's a short demonstration program showing such a 'target-independent' conversion:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define MAXLEN 256

int main()
{
    TCHAR output[MAXLEN]; // Type can be either `char` or `wchar_t`
    const char* input = "SELECT * FROM...";

    _stprintf(output, TEXT("%hs"), input); // Resolves to either "sprintf" or "_swprintf"

    _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), output); // Just to show the result!
    return 0;
}
```

You could also declare a (static inline) function, `VARTEXT`, that does the conversion (but you would need to either supply an output buffer, or create and manage one in that function):

```c
static inline TCHAR* VARTEXT(const char* input, TCHAR* output)
{
    _stprintf(output, TEXT("%hs"), input);
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    TCHAR output[MAXLEN];
    const char* input = "SELECT * FROM...";
    _tprintf(TEXT("%s\n"), VARTEXT(input, output));
    return 0;
}
```